# создание диаграммы в Umbrello

Tags: uml

Как автоматически создать диаграмму классов в Umbrello?

Comment: Может быть этот вариант поможет - https://docs.kde.org/stable4/en/kdesdk/umbrello/code-import.html

Comment: Для чего было удалять комментарии?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из [справочника](https://docs.kde.org/stable4/en/kdesdk/umbrello/code-import.html):

Umbrello UML Modeller не будет создавать диаграммы для показа ваших классов, они будут импортированы только в вашу Модель так, что вы можете использовать их позже. После того, как вы сделали это, вы просто перетаскиваете элементы на диаграмму класса, в последствии они буду связаны для вас.